# Removing Chrome Resources after removing them from HTML via Javascript

Tags: javascript, memory-management, google-chrome

I am currently developing an application with the intention of only using chrome, one of the properties of the application is that it dynamically attaches javascript files and runs them.
When they are done executing, the script tags get removed. Due to the nature of the application I am trying to refrain from refreshing the page.

**My issue is that Chrome keeps these files as resources (can view this in developer tools), and keeps running them. As a result, chromes memory usage goes up and up.**

Is there anyway to stop Chrome from keeping these resources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you may have some [reference leaks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak#Reference_counting_and_cyclic_references). Instead of trying to explicitly unload the no-longer-needed javascript module's representation in the dom, you might try stopping the old code from executing (e.g. returning from methods, unregistering event handlers, setTimeout and setInterval handles, etc), then explicitly setting any references to values in the module's scope to null.

It's only once you've cleaned up all these references that the garbage collector will deallocate the memory (as that's the only unequivocally safe time for it to do so).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yeah I have yet to fix the reference leaks, but I know what is happening. Due to the nature of some forever loops implemented in some of the scripts, it seems that when you remove them , they still continue in that loop, even after they are removed from the dom. My solution is to override setInterval and setTimeout to check for a global condition to stop execution. Thanks.